# Displaying Data in GridView on click event, Search Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search, gridview

i have placed a gridview on my page and linked it to LinqDataSourceFemale (Female Table of Database) and i have a search event code like the below one

```
    protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(BerouDataContext Data = new BerouDataContext())
        {
              if (DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text == "Male")
              {

                  int age = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListAge.Text);
                  string education = DropDownListEducation.Text.ToString();
                  string maritalstatus = DropDownListMaritalStatus.Text.ToString();
                  //var religion = DropDownListReligion.Text.ToString();
                  string caste = DropDownListCaste.Text.ToString();
                  string city = DropDownListCity.ToString();

                  var SearchResultBoys = Data.Males.Where(tan =>
                      (tan.Age == age)
                      && (tan.Education == education)
                      && (tan.Group == maritalstatus)
                      && (tan.Caste == caste));

                  GridViewMale.DataSourceID = "";
                  GridViewMale.DataSource = SearchResultBoys;
                  GridViewMale.DataBind();
              }
              else if (DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text == "Female")
              {
                  int age = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListAge.Text);
                  string education = DropDownListEducation.Text.ToString();
                  string maritalstatus = DropDownListMaritalStatus.Text.ToString();
                  //var religion = DropDownListReligion.Text.ToString();
                  string caste = DropDownListCaste.Text.ToString();
                  string city = DropDownListCity.ToString();

                  var SearchResultGirls = Data.Females.Where(tan =>
                      (tan.Age == age)
                      && (tan.Education == education)
                      && (tan.Group == maritalstatus)
                      && (tan.Caste == caste));

                  GridViewFemale.DataSourceID = "";
                  GridViewFemale.DataSource = SearchResultGirls;
                  GridViewFemale.DataBind();



              }
        }
    }
```

grid view doesnt appear after button click, please help me.

Comment: Might be a postback thing. Are you creating the grid dymanically?

Comment: i have put a gridview on a page and linked it to a database table, and in the code i have done this --> GridViewFemale.DataSource = SearchResultsGirls; , GridViewFemale.DataBind();

Comment: LinqDataSourceFemale, GridViewFemale ooh man. http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist the data in some fashion. It appears that after the button is clicked, a postback occurs and you lose it. One thing you might check on where the databinding fires, ensure that it is caught on subsequent postbacks.

Another thing you could do is simply store the data in a session variable, and upon postback re-bind the gridview with the data.

When the data is first retrieved, you could assign it to a session variable:

```
Session.Add("searchResultBoys", SearchResultBoys);
Session.Add("searchResultGirls", SearchResultGirls);
```

Then for example on subsuquent pageloads you could:

```
GridViewMale.DataSource = (DataTable)Session[searchResultBoys]; //be sure to cast whatever the datasource is, in my example I just used DataTable
GridViewFemale.DataSource = (DataTable)Session[searchResultGirls];
```

EDIT:

So in order to persist the data in a session variable, we have to save the var SearchResultBoys and SearchResultGirls into a type (in this case a datatable). Becuase saving the var in a session will just save the query expression and not the result set. Try converting your var SearchResultBoys and SearchResultGirls to this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> SearchResultsBoys = Data.Males.Where(tan =>
            (tan.Age == age)
            && (tan.Education == education)
            && (tan.Group == maritalstatus)
            && (tan.Caste == caste));
```

Then what we can do is assign that result to a datatable - where it can be stored in memory) and persisted.

```
DataTable dt = SearchResultsBoys.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Now you can bind the data as before:

```
 GridViewMale.DataSourceID = "";
 GridViewMale.DataSource = SearchResultBoys;
 GridViewMale.DataBind();
```

Once that is working for you on the girls and boys data, then I can show you how to persist using a session or global variable.

Comment: Can you please show me this by adding this code in my above code.

Comment: OOPS Sorry for the trouble it is working with my code, what i did was assigning dropdownlist values to search and not using them. But Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `GridViewFemale.DataSourceID = "";` line

And are you bind `gridview` in page load  inside of  `!IsPostBack`?

If it not bind,Please bind  `gridview`  in inside of !`IsPostBack` in `pageload` event

Edit

the coding for

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
// here is Bind gridview code .
}
}
```